# Show $\lim_{N \to \infty} \mathbb{E} [ X_N \mathbb{I}\{ X_N > b\}] = 0$.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expected-value, conditional-expectation

Assume that a sequence of positive random variables $X_N$ converges almost surely to some constant $a$. Moreover, their expectation also converges to $a$.

$\lim_{N \to \infty} X_N = a \hspace{3mm} \text{a.s.}, \hspace{3mm} \lim_{N \to \infty} \mathbb{E}[X_N] = a.$

Is it true that $\lim_{N \to \infty} \mathbb{E} \big[ X_N \mathbb{I}\{ X_N > b\} \big] = 0$ for a constant $b > a$?

Can we replace the almost sure convergence with the convergence in probability?

Comment: Is $\Bbb I$ notation for an indicator function, or did you mean to condition $X_N$ on $X_N>b$?

Comment: It is indicator function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Consider the variables $X_N$ that takes value $2^N$ with probability $2^{-N}$, $-2^N$ with probability $2^{-N}$, and $0$ otherwise. Then

1. $\sum_N P(X_N \neq 0) < \infty$, so $X_N \to 0$ almost surely.
2. For any $b > 0$, we have $E(X_N1_{X_N > b}) = 1$ for sufficiently large $N$.

But if $X_N$ is non-negative then the proposition is true. For if we let $Y_N = X_N 1_{X_N \leq b}$, then $Y_N \to a$ almost surely, thus by bounded convergence we have
$$\lim_{N \to \infty} E(Y_N) = a.$$
So
$$\lim_{N \to \infty} E(X_N - Y_N) = 0$$
as desired.

Comment: You are right. But, if we add the positivity assumption, do we have the result?

Comment: Not sure. I’ll think about it after a while.

Comment: You could just modify so that they take the value $2^N$ with probability $2^{-N}/N$ and are $0$ elsewhere. Btw, in this example $X_N$ converges to $0$ also in probability, hence this is a counter example to the second question as well.

Comment: @JonathanHole, in this example I think the result holds in fact. Because the contribution from the large part is 1/N which converges 0.

Comment: @ShengtongZhang, thanks for the answer. Can we relax the assumption from almost sure convergence to convergence in probability?